# Android tabs with ActionBarSherlock and fragments using newInstance

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

I've just set up a project using tabs + actionbarsherlock + fragments, and want to make sure my approach is correct before moving on - mainly the use of my `onTabSelected` calling `newInstance`, this example is derived from CommonsWare's https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ActionBar/TabFragmentDemo sample code.

My TabFragmentActivity:

```
public class TabFragmentActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity
implements TabListener {

private static final String KEY_POSITION="position";

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
    super.onCreate(state);

    ActionBar bar=getSupportActionBar();
    bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    bar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    bar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

    bar.addTab(bar.newTab().setText(R.string.tab1)
            .setTabListener(this).setTag(0));

    bar.addTab(bar.newTab().setText(R.string.tab2)
            .setTabListener(this).setTag(1));

    bar.addTab(bar.newTab().setText(R.string.tab3)
            .setTabListener(this).setTag(2));

    bar.addTab(bar.newTab().setText(R.string.tab4)
            .setTabListener(this).setTag(3));

    if (state != null) {
      bar.setSelectedNavigationItem(state.getInt(KEY_POSITION));
    }
  }

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle state) {
  state.putInt(KEY_POSITION,
               getSupportActionBar().getSelectedNavigationIndex());
}  

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    int i=((Integer)tab.getTag()).intValue();

    if (i == 0){
        ft.replace(android.R.id.content,
                Tab1Fragment.newInstance(i));           
    }
    else if (i == 1){
        ft.replace(android.R.id.content,
                Tab2Fragment.newInstance(i));           
    }
    else if (i == 2){
        ft.replace(android.R.id.content,
                Tab3Fragment.newInstance(i));           
    }
    else if (i == 3){
        ft.replace(android.R.id.content,
                Tab4Fragment.newInstance(i));           
    }

}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

My Tab1Fragment:

```
public class Tab1Fragment extends SherlockFragment {
    private static final String KEY_POSITION="position";

    static Tab1Fragment newInstance(int position) {
        Tab1Fragment frag=new Tab1Fragment();
        Bundle args=new Bundle();

        args.putInt(KEY_POSITION, position);
        frag.setArguments(args);

        return(frag);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View result=inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);

        return(result);
    }

}
```

Where my Tab1Fragment will eventually do a lot of AsyncTask heavy loading - is this ok as well?

Comment: I have no idea if your "approach is correct", as I do not know what you are trying to do. StackOverflow works much better with concrete questions.

Comment: @CommonsWare I get it, less theory more specific problem. For this case could you assume Tab1Fragment will retrieve data in AsyncTask and display in list view, Tab2Fragment will be a viewpager for an imageview that pages through images, and the other two will do the same as Tab1Fragment.

Comment: Um, that did not really help.